# GoalUpdater-bt_navigator-behavior_tree Updating a goal to /navigate_to_pose not responding

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to find a way to update a goal passed to the action /navigate_to_pose since calling a new action would result in aborting the previous one. I found the bt plugin GoalUpdater which should do the magic but when I try to use it basically nothing happens when I publish on /goal_update topic.

ROS_DISTRO: galactic
UBUNTU: 20.04

##### bt_navigator.xml:

```
<BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">
    <Sequence name="Test">
        <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-test" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
      <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-test" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
      <Wait wait_duration="1"/>
<RecoveryNode number_of_retries="6" name="NavigateRecovery">
    <PipelineSequence name="NavigateWithReplanning">
      <RateController hz="10.0">
        <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="ComputePathToPose">
          <GoalUpdater input_goal="{goal}" output_goal="{updated_goal}">
            <ComputePathToPose goal="{updated_goal}" path="{path}" planner_id="GridBased"/>
          </GoalUpdater>
          <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
        </RecoveryNode>
      </RateController>
      <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="DynamicFollowPath">
        <FollowPath path="{path}" controller_id="DynamicFollowPath"/>
        <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Context" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
      </RecoveryNode>
    </PipelineSequence>
  <ReactiveFallback name="RecoveryFallback">
    <GoalUpdated/>
    <SequenceStar name="RecoveryActions">
      <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
      <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
      <Wait wait_duration="1"/>
    </SequenceStar>
  </ReactiveFallback>
</RecoveryNode>
</Sequence>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402705/goalupdater-bt_navigator-behavior_tree-updating-a-goal-to-/navigate_to_pose-not-responding/) by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2022-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those who are interested, it turned out goalUpdater node was receiving the goal_update topic but inside the plugin there is a check on the timestamps and since I was sending a message without timestamp the plugin was just discarding it. It has been sufficient to fill the timestamp in the header fo the message and GoalUpdater made the magic

---

Originally posted by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) with karma: 71 on 2022-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1